# How can a question be marked as a duplicate if it's been asked **earlier** than a similar question?

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicates

[This question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/25591/does-the-universe-have-a-center)  has been asked 6 years and 10 months ago. How can it be a duplicate of [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/136860/did-the-big-bang-happen-at-a-point), which has been asked 4 years and 4 months ago? Shouldn't the second be marked as a duplicate?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147651/271002

Comment: Related: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8964/2451

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Shouldn't the second be marked as a duplicate?

In this specific case, the first question (together with its answers) is noticeably less clear and useful than the second one, and indeed it covers a strict subset of the latter. How would it help the site to close the second one as a duplicate of the first one?

---

On the other hand, I *am* bothered by the fact that the $1\to 2$ duplicate closure happened as a result of a unilateral action on the part of the author of the Q&A at the second question, which to my mind kind of over-steps what the [dupehammer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders) should be used for. A more appropriate course of action would have been to vote this into the closure queue and let the community decide, I should think.

Still, in this instance I agree with the closure, so I'm not throwing any stones.

Comment: It seems relevant to mention that the second thread is a CW.

Comment: @Qmechanic Sure, but that doesn't much change my opinion on that closure - that should've gone through the queue. It's a conflict of interest, CW or not.